# VK API user.get - почему некоторые поля пустые?

Tags: java, json, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Разбираюсь с vk api. Хочу вытащить информацию о пользователе по полям games,education,occupation. На тестовой странице по https://vk.com/dev/users.get возвращаются все поля:
[image: то что выдает тестовая форма]

Но когда делаю через JAVA SDK. Приходят не все поля:
[image: мой ответ]

Вот фрагмент моего кода:

```
String str = vk.users().get(new UserActor(app_id, access_token))
                .userIds("5933129")
                .fields(UserField.EDUCATION,
                        UserField.GAMES,
                        UserField.OCCUPATION)
                .executeAsString();
System.out.println(str);
```

Из документации узнал, что

[image: дока]

Но я же вроде передаю access_token через объект UserActor, или я что то не так понимаю. В качестве access_token использую 'Сервисный ключ доступа' который взял из настроек в личном кабинете приложения.

Попробовал через браузер выполнить:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids=5933129&fields=games,education,occupation&access_token=xxxxxxx3&v=5.69
```

также приходит hidden : 1

Вопрос как добиться, чтобы возвращались все поля?

Comment: Тело вашего запроса есть возможность увидеть? Залогируйте и проверьте параметры.

Comment: Была такая идея, но я не нашел как вывести в лог запрос. Может знаете?

Comment: access_token можно получить через OAuth. В ответе Виктора есть ссылка на страницу документации. Однако меня сюда привело именно то, что проблема осталась.

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы выполняете запрос через страницу https://vk.com/dev/users.get вы выполняете его с ключом доступа пользователя.

Видимо пользователь скрыл интересующие вас данные от неавторизованных пользователей.

Чтобы все работало нормально вам надо получить [ключ доступа пользователя](https://vk.com/dev/access_token?f=1.%20%D0%9A%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)